# Write a fopen function in assembly

Tags: c, file, fopen, inline-assembly, turbo-c++

I am trying to implement `fopen` in turbo c++ 3.0, I need to write it in asm inline.

I wrote a code, but (no suprise....) it's not working (compilation failed).

The code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_fopen_w(char fname[])
{
    int fd;
    char status;
    status = 'w'; // I need to write to a file and delete previous content
    asm{
        mov bl, status
        xor bh,bh
        push bp
        mov bp, sp
        push bx
        push fname
        //Same as fopen now fopen(file path= fname, "w" = bx)
        call _fopen
        add sp,8

        // Returned value in AX register 
        mov fd, ax  // That line may be incorrect, my teacher demands an Integer returned value  

    }
    return fd;
}
```

I got an error: turbo c does not recognize `_fopen` call.

[image: Error with "call _fopen"]

[image: Error with "call fopen"]
Thanks for any help.

Haim

Comment: You need to declare `_fopen` to be a global object somehow (i.e. `.global _fopen` at the beginning of your assembler code)

Comment: Why are you practising assembler programming for MS DOS?

Comment: It is a homework

Comment: I also wrote another function that implements fclose function in assembly  (very short and simple function) and turbo c is not recognize _fclose line.............

Comment: Warning, `fopen` expects a `char*` as second argument, you are giving just a `char`

Comment: OK, I will change it, but still, It does not recognize any C function!!!! not fopen,  fclose, printf and so on..... using "extern" to the function doesn`t help.

Comment: @Haim And why is your school teaching you to be a year 1990 programmer? You need to ask them why you aren't taught things that would actually give you a job instead.

Comment: It is not an issue now, I asked for help, the reason why I practice assembly is not important.

Comment: Insert a c-call to _fopen and have a look at the generated asm-code. Maybe, there's another _ and you have to call __fopen?

Comment: I have to call _fopen, that the way we learned. for the rest of your comment, I am not sure what do you mean?

Comment: I know that the problem is with the "call" to the function, I tried it on printf("vvx") and getch(); just by calling: "call _printf", and "call _getch". With "_" before the name of the function, the complier does not recognize the line. without the "_" before the name, turbo c says: " Invalid combination of opcode and opperands". I am looking fo example in the internet. so far non of them talking about tasm compiler (turbo c)....

Comment: Are you sure that it is an assembler error, not a linker error?

Comment: Another guess: If you compile as C++ (instead of C), a different name mangling is used. Have you checked for that?

Comment: The compiler is Turbo c++

Comment: I just added 2 pictures with the errors. The compile is turbo c++ 3.0.

Comment: Yes, I do, but the error is the same!!

Comment: I just don`t understand why it's happening to me! I know something is missing here, but I don`t know what. All examples I found on the internet are not working. all of them based on other compilers.

Comment: Another guess: In DOS (real mode) one has to consider the memory model, especially if pointers are `far` or `near`. "Invalid combination of opcode and operandi" could indicate, that the type of the operand is not correct. Maybe you should follow the advice of @Holger and generate an assembler file from a C-File by the option "-S" (see Chapter 5 of the Borland User Guide) and check, if some prefixes or so are generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Turbo C 3.0. TCC 3.0 by default links the C library into the CODE segment, so you can load  `AX` with the address of the C function (you don't need the underscore) and then use `CALL AX`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    char fname[] = "noname.txt";
    char status[] = "wb";
    FILE * fd;
    asm{
        lea ax, status
        push ax
        lea ax, fname
        push ax

        lea ax, fopen
        call ax

        pop cx
        pop cx
        mov fd, ax
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: `fopen` needs two pointers to two strings. Both pointers are unknown at compile time. So you have to use `LEA` to get them at run time, except somebody else (operating system, C startup code etc.) has got the pointer for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE*  my_fopen_w(char fname[])
{
    FILE * fd;
    char  status[]="wt";
    int my_fd;

    asm{
        lea ax, status
        push ax
        mov ax, fname               // fname was passed as a pointer ("Call by value")
        push ax

        lea ax, fopen
        call ax

        pop cx
        pop cx
        mov fd, ax
    }
    return fd;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  FILE * fd;

  fd = my_fopen_w(argv[1]);         // argv[1] is a pointer to a string
  fputs("Here I am.", fd);
  fclose(fd);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much!! Its really pass compilation. But it is not working on running..... I can`t open a new file, the program doesn`t show failure, but the file did not create!

Comment: @Haim - If rkhb's answer solved the question you asked please consider accepting it (and if you want upvote it as well). As for your code that isn't working it is because you have used LEA in some places you should have used MOV. A revised one that may work is here: capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/asmio.c

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!! Its working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   Thank you!!!!!! You saved my life!!!!

Comment: So the bug is that Turbo C doesn't allow `call fopen` like the OP's 2nd example which shows a screenshot of "invalid combination of opcode and operands"?  That is weird; maybe it doesn't know how to do rel16 offsets, only absolute.   BTW, there's zero advantage to LEA over `mov ax, offset fopen`.  Using `lea` for `[disp16]` addressing modes just wastes a byte of code-size.  You do want `lea` for non-static arrays, though: they probably compile into `lea ax, [bp-8]` or whatever, since you made a local char array (with the string bytes copied to the stack), instead of a `static const`.

Comment: Just a side note. This bug seems specific to Turbo-C's internal assembler. I agree with @PeterCordes it looks like it doesn't handle relative calls within inline assembly. I happened to play around with this issue this morning and did notice that it does work if you use TCC 3.0x `-B` option for compiling. `-B` will force TCC to output an assembly file and then call TASM externally to assemble the file to an object (bypassing the internal assembler). With `-B` it does appear to work.